# finding the area using integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

> Find the area blocked between X-Y axis and $x=\pi$, $y=\sin x$ according to $x$ and $y$.

According to x: $\int_0^\pi \sin x \, dx=-\cos(\pi)+\cos(0)=2$

According to $y$: $\int_0^1 (\pi- \sin^{-1} y)\,dy=\left[\pi y-\sin^{-1}y + \sqrt{1-y^2}\right]_0^1 = \pi-\frac{2}{\pi}+1=\frac{2}{\pi}+1$

Where did I get it wrong?

Comment: When you integrated $\int_0^1 (\pi-\sin^{-1}y)dy$, how $2/\pi$ appeared?

Comment: @choco_addicted right forgot $1$ edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just took a mistake while integrating according to $y$.

[image]

You have to integrate
$$
\int_0^1 ((\pi-\sin^{-1}y)-\sin^{-1}y)dy.
$$
**Edit:** If you stick to find $\int_0^1 (\pi - \sin^{-1}y)dy$, you will find wrong answer, because you fail to calculate colored area only, containing area $\mathrm{ABO}$.

[image]

Comment: Why I need to take$\int_0^1 ((\pi-\sin^{-1}y)-\sin^{-1}y)dy.
$? why the extra $-\sin^{-1}y$

Comment: @gbox I added some description, do you understand?

Comment: Yes, Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

$\sin^{-1}$ is the inverse of the restriction of the function $\sin$ to the interval $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$.  But you're working with areas outside of that interval.

Answer (score 1):

I don't get the second approach, since $\sin (x)=\sin (\pi-x)$ Would it be $2\int _0^1 \left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\sin ^{-1}y\right)dy=\left(-\sqrt{1-y^2}+\frac{\pi  y}{2}+y \left(-\sin ^{-1}(y)\right)\right)\left.\right|_0^1=2$? Hope it will help

Comment: I need to show that integrating according to X and Y get the same answer.

In you case you are right, but why do I need to use $sin(\pi-x)$?

Comment: @gbox I think that is the reason to write the integral as $2\int _0^1...$ which means to calculate just half of the area and times 2, because there is a symmetry to make sure the other half is as same as one calculated.